# Can I upload WebPlusX6?

Tags: software-installation

I am a new Ubuntu user.  Can I upload WebPlusX6 to Ubuntu?  It's a program used to create websites that is offered by Serif.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need a real version of Microsoft Windows; Windows XP or newer.

You could run this copy of Windows either by arranging a dual-boot of your hardware, or possibly on a virtualiser such as VirtualBox running on top of Linux.

Then install and run WebPlus as normal.

Depending on your needs and level of skill, there are HTML editors which run directly on Linux or on JAVA.

and yes you can not use wine as its not supported by wine..

answer taken from https://community.serif.com/forum/webplus/4960/how-can-i-install-webplus-x6-on-linux-ubuntu-os

Answer (score 0):

As I have seen from [serif community](https://community.serif.com/forum/webplus/4960/how-can-i-install-webplus-x6-on-linux-ubuntu-os) . They are saying that you cant install it Linux directly. you need windows to run.

Comment: they have written you need a real version of microsoft , and linux can be used for editing HTML and running them on linux

Comment: can and cant only t has changed the meaning. thank you for noticing my type errors.